# How do i connect google cloud sql with circle-ci at the time of performing testing

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, google-cloud-sql, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have written some test cases in which i do require database data which is stored in google cloud sql. Now at the time of deployment i want to run my all the test cases. In few of test cases data need to be fetch from database. At this point how am i supposed to configure my test case so that, whenever database data required i can connect google cloud sql to circle-ci.
Locally i have created connection via cloud SSL and public IP. I have no idea how am i suppose to connect my database when Test cases are running in circle-ci ?

any help appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to installing mysql-cli | cloud sdk | and then connecting via proxy authentication (instance mode) but that required terminal in running mode.

Comment: Also tried to via service account file still not working.

Comment: I can not use SSL proxy as IP may not be static for circle-ci

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when trying to connect with a service account or proxy?